# Value moved into closure in previous iteration of loop

Tags: multithreading, rust, move, borrow-checker, raytracing

I'm trying to use parallelization in a small raytracer I'm implementing.

The idea is that I generate a image pixel by pixel using a function `cast_ray()`, so I would like to spawn a new thread for each pixel to speed up calculation.

Basically, I am computing an 2D array of a given size.
I uses Messages to update an array with the color values.

My renderer function looks like this (I deleted some parts for clarity):

```rust
pub fn render_parallel(scene: Scene) -> Vec<Vec<(u8, u8, u8)>> {
    // A small 100x100 2D array
    let mut image = vec![vec![(0, 0, 0); 100]; 100];

    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    for x in -50..50 {
        for y in -50..50 {
            // Clone the message emitter
            let tx_cell = tx.clone();
            
            // Spawn a new thread for the pixel
            thread::spawn(move || {
                let ray = ... // A new ray from the camera ;
                let color = cast_ray(
                    &ray, 
                    &scene);

                // Send the coordinates & values to the receiver
                tx_cell.send((
                        ((24 - y) as usize, (25 + x) as usize),
                        (color.r, color.g, color.b)))
                    .unwrap();
            });
        }
    }

    for ((i, j), (r, g, b)) in rx {
        image[i][j] = (r, g, b)
    }

    image
}

pub struct Scene {
    pub primitives: Vec<Box<dyn Primitive + Sync>>,
    pub lights: Vec<Box<dyn Light + Sync>>,
}

pub trait Primitive : Send + Sync {
    // Some functions...
}

pub trait Light: Send + Sync {
    // Some functions...
}
```

The thing is, it doesn't work, and Rust is throwing me the following error :

```
413 | pub fn render_parallel(scene: Scene) -> Vec<Vec<(u8, u8, u8)>>{
    |                        ----- move occurs because `scene` has type `Scene`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
421 |             thread::spawn(move || {
    |                           ^^^^^^^ value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop
...
428 |                     &scene,
    |                      ----- use occurs due to use in closure
```

I don't understand why the value is moved when I'm only using a reference to it.
My other version of `render()` without using threads is the same as above, without the `tx`, `rx` and `thread::spawn()` and doesn't run into any issue, which confuses me more.

How can I use the `scene` variable in multiple simultaneous closures (if I'm understanding the problem correctly)?

Comment: Re, "...new thread for each pixel..." I don't know how much work it takes to calculate one pixel, but it takes a significant amount of work to create and destroy one thread. Consider using a [_thread pool_](https://docs.rs/threadpool/latest/threadpool/) that has approximately the same number of worker threads as your host has CPU cores.

Comment: @SolomonSlow indeed the result was quite underwhelming, as it took more time to generate an image with this new function compared to the "no-multithreading" one. Thanks a lot! I'll look into it.

Comment: (Sorry for the double post) but using a thread pool worked wonders!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scene` is moved into the closure because you specify `move`.  To borrow `scene`, you need to rebind it as a reference before you spawn the thread, for example:

```
let tx_cell = tx.clone();
let scene = &scene;
```

This rebinds `scene` in that scope to be a reference to the outer `scene`.  The reference is then moved into the closure.

However, this will fail because `thread::spawn()` expects a `'static` closure (one that does not borrow from its environment) because there is no guarantee the thread will terminate before the value being borrowed is destroyed.  In your code, this should not happen because you exhaust `rx` before `scene` would be dropped, but the type system doesn't know this.

Instead, consider wrapping `scene` in an [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html).  This gives you thread-safe shared ownership of `scene`.  You can then clone the `Arc` handle and give a different handle to each thread; each handle will reference the same `Scene` value.

Insert this as the first line of the function:

```
let scene = Arc::new(scene);
```

Then clone the `Arc` when you clone `tx`:

```
let tx_cell = tx.clone();
let scene = Arc::clone(scene);
```

`&scene` in your closure will auto-deref the `Arc`, so you don't need to change that.

---

Another approach would be to use [crossbeam's scoped threads](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) which permit non-static borrows by guaranteeing that spawned threads must terminate before the scope is destroyed.

If you take this approach, note that you should move the `for` loop into the scope so that it can receive messages in parallel as the spawned threads send them.  If you place it after the scope, the threads will send all messages and terminate before you start to process the messages, which means all of the messages must be held in memory at one time.

---

As a side note, there is a bug in your code that will cause a deadlock: `tx` lives while you read from `rx`, so the loop reading from `rx` will never terminate as there is an open sender that could be used to send more messages.  Add `drop(tx);` before the `for` loop to close your thread's local sender.

Comment: Wow, I never thought that I would get such an eloquent and exhaustive answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that [scoped threads are available in the standard library now](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html).

Comment: @Jmb Nice. I stop paying attention to releases for a few months and everything I want finally gets stabilized, go figure.